# How to sort numbers in an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var set = [3,100, 70, 55, 47, 202];
var sortedNumbers = set.sort();
console.log(sortedNumbers)
```

I see the following in the console:

```
[100, 202, 3, 47, 55, 70]
```

Why isn't the array sorted?

Comment: it's sorted as a string by default

Comment: set.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});

Comment: Please try searching before asking questions that are easily answered on the web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sort` function treats the array values as strings. Instead you could use:

```
    function sortNumber(a, b) {
        return a - b;
    }

    var sortedNumbers = set.sort(sortNumber);
```